# convert a time-string like "11:00" or "14:00" to decimal time like 1.75?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, icalendar

I found this function on the php-manual "date".

```
<?php 
// Converts a unix timestamp to iCal format (UTC) - if no timezone is 
// specified then it presumes the uStamp is already in UTC format. 
// tzone must be in decimal such as 1hr 45mins would be 1.75, behind 
// times should be represented as negative decimals 10hours behind 
// would be -10 

    function unixToiCal($uStamp = 0, $tzone = 0.0) { 

        $uStampUTC = $uStamp + ($tzone * 3600);        
        $stamp  = date("Ymd\THis\Z", $uStampUTC); 

        return $stamp;        

    } 
?>
```

I have a variable like `$event_time[0]` that holds a timeformat like this `14:00` which would be 2pm. How can I convert this timeformat so that is decimal to pass it along to the `unixToiCal()` function above?

Thanks for your response.

**Update:**
Well, it seems like I'm completely confused. Thanks guys for clearing things up. Didn't really get what the second param of the function was for. I'm from Austria, so the UTC offset should be `+2` hours, right.

There is another question I have with the `strtotime()` method.

I have two variables … `$time` and `$date` … the problem I have with this is that `$date` already is a timestamp like `1347667200` and `$time` is a "string" (i guess) `11:00` or `14:00`.

How can I combine those two values two a timestamp that represents the exact date and the time?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? In that example, the 1.75 represents the timezone offset, not the hours. To me, it looks like that example totally ignores proper daylight saving time.

Comment: Timestamp holds number of milliseconds since `epoch` (Jan 1st, 1970), so if you got just hours, it quite insufficient unless you are fine with your iCal entry dated Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com - seconds, not milliseconds.  This isn't Javascript. Note the math assumes 3600 per hour.

Comment: Correct in case of code above, but I referred to common meaning of unix timestamp, which holds millis since epoch. It looks I wasn't precise enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that [my post helped you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234925/php-writing-a-ics-ical-file-date-formatting/12234958#12234958) further!

The function you're working with needs a [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instances in
>   time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), January 1, 1970,  not
>   counting leap seconds.

Therefore a time value alone doesn't help you further, you need a date component too, otherwise you can't calculate the unix time.

Here's an example how to convert something to a unix time in php:

```
$date_to_unixtime = strtotime('3rd September 2012 18:33:34 PM (UTC)');
```

**Update:**

You can add a time value to a unix time in php like this:

```
$your_new_timestamp = $your_current_timestamp 
    + ($hours * 3600) 
    + ($minutes * 60)
    + $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused.  What are you trying to do?

The function `unixToiCal` expects a UNIX timestamp.  That is the number of non-leap seconds since January 1st, 1970, at midnight GMT.  There are a number of ways of getting such a thing, but you can't "convert" a time of day like "14:00" to one, because 2pm corresponds to different timestamps on different days.  It's absolute, not relative to midnight.

The decimal value mentioned in the comment is for the *time zone offset*.  That is almost always going to be a whole number of hours anyway, but if you're dealing with one of the places that has a non-whole number of hours offset from UTC, then you have to convert it into hours rather than hours+minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` to convert a date and time string to a timestamp.